# memory error in struct list (storage uknown)

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct, constants

i'm trying to compile this code but i get a memory error:    list1.c:25:15: error: storage size of ‘cnodo’ isn’t known
   struct nobo cnodo;

so can anybody tell me what is the source of this error and how to avoid it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct nodo {
    int info;
    struct nodo *prec;
    struct nodo *succ;
    } ;
typedef struct nodo nodo;




void stampa (struct nodo *p);


int main (void) {

    struct nodo *p;


    struct nodo anodo;
    struct nodo bnodo;
    struct nobo cnodo;

    anodo.info = 99;
    anodo.prec = NULL;
    anodo.succ = NULL;



    bnodo.info = 1010;
    bnodo.prec = NULL;
    bnodo.succ = NULL;


    cnodo.info = 1020;
    cnodo.prec = NULL;
    cnodo.succ = NULL;

    anodo.succ = &bnodo;    
    bnodo.prec = &anodo;
    bnodo.succ = &cnodo;    
    cnodo.prec = &bnodo;

    p = &anodo;

    stampa(p);


    return 0;

    }


void stampa (struct nodo *p) {

    while (p != NULL) {

        printf("\n nodo value is : %d \n ", p -> info);
        p = p -> succ;

        }
    }
```

Comment: First of all try to check your program line by line and then post it here. You have just a typographical mistake in your code which you can resolve just by checking line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's

```
struct nodo cnodo;
```

not

```
struct nobo cnodo;
     /*  ^ d not b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct nobo cnodo;
```

should be

```
struct nodo cnodo;
```

(typo)

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo there. Change

```
 struct nobo cnodo;
```

to

```
struct nodo cnodo;
```